# Parse cloud function

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am implementing cloud code to my parse application. I have two tables/class, one is of Product list and another is of Reviews. Review class contain pointer of Product. Now I want average rating on that particular Product.

Below is my function :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("averageRating",function(request, response){
var query=new Parse.Query("Reviews");
query.include("Product");
query.equalTo("ProductPointer",ParseObject.createWithoutData("Product", request.params.ProductPointer));
query.find({
    success: function(results){
        var sum=0;
        for(var i=0; i<results.length; ++i){
            sum += results[i].get("starRating");
        }
        response.success(product.id);
    },
    error:function(){
        response.error("Review lookup failed");
    }
});
```

});

But I am getting following error:

```
ReferenceError: ParseObject is not defined at main.js
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: typo `reponse` in function definition.

Answer (score 0):

ParseObject is not part of the JavaScript API, but it exists in the Android API and the .Net API.

Comment: So, how can I match Pointer object in cloud function? I had tried this also, but its not working  var   Product=Parse.Object.extend("Product");
 var item=new Product();
 item.id=request.params.ProductPointer;
 query.equalTo("ProductPointer",item);

Comment: You do not match the pointer, but the object itself. Fetch the object you want to match and then use query.equalTo("ProductPointer", theObject);

Comment: Can't I create temporary object with that id?

Comment: No, I don't think you can. Parse handles the comparison behind the scenes and so a temporary object with that id will not compute to the same object. But aren't you checking reviews against the current product object? I'm guessing the averageRating is for some kind of current product, and so I would believe you should already have a handle to the product object you want to use in your query constraint...?

Comment: Actaully I need top 10 highly rated products.

Comment: So, what are you using the ProductPointer constraint for? Why not just query for "Reviews", order by rating and include("Product")?

Comment: Just to be picky: My answer is the correct answer to why you experience the error in your question. Your first comment is actually a new question, and should not be asked in a comment :-)

Comment: It should be based on average rating, that's why. Sorry, that I asked this question in comment. I am a newbie to this cloud functions and facing many problems. So I am just searching for my required implementation. Hope you understand. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51875/discussion-between-handsomeguy-and-ankita-shah)